# Erlang:How to load sys.config in console?

Tags: intellij-idea, erlang

I'm using Intellij IDEA with erlang plugin, compiled with rebar. When I start console in Intellij, run

```
application:load(eddy).
application:start(eddy).
```

In my code, application:get_env always returns undefined.Does sys.config only available under release?

Answer (score 3):

Calling application:load() (or start()) will only read the application's .app file, not any sys.config file you might have. If you're not using releases, you can start Erlang with "erl -config sys.config".

Comment: Start erlang with "erl -config sys.config" in command line is ok, but start in Intellij with "-config sys.config" args still no effect.Maybe it's an Intellij specific issue?